# how to write a multithread kivy game(on rasp Pi) that can listen to a port at the same time

Tags: python, multithreading, raspberry-pi, kivy, raspbian

I am writing a remote-control snake game on Raspberry Pi using kivy(output to the 7" display). 
The socket is supposed to listen to the port while the game is running.
However it turns out that game loop and socketIO's wait loop can not run together. I tried multithreading but it didn't work as expected.

Code for socketIO:

```
from socketIO_client import SocketIO, BaseNamespace
class Namespace(BaseNamespace):
    def on_connect(self):
        print('[Connected]')
    def on_message(self,packet):
        print packet
        self.get_data(packet)        

    def get_data(self, packet):        
        if(type(packet) is str):
            matches = re.findall(PATTERN, packet)            
            if(matches[0][0]=='2'):                
                dataMatches = re.findall(DATAPATTERN, matches[0][4])
                print dataMatches
                ......
```

Code for main that definitely does not work:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyKeyboardListener() #keyboard listener, works fine
    SnakeApp().run()
    socketIO = SocketIO('10.0.0.4',8080,Namespace)
    socketIO.wait()
```

I tried the following multithreading, but it didn't work:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyKeyboardListener() #keyboard listener, works fine
    threading.Thread(target = SnakeApp().run).start() #results in abort
    socketIO = SocketIO('10.0.0.4',8080,Namespace)
    socketIO.wait()
```

The above code results in making program to abort with error message :"Fatal Python error: (pygame parachute) Segmentation Fault
Aborted"

I also tried another multithreading method but it didn't work as well. This is really frustrating. Is there any way to let game loop and socketIO's wait loop run at the same time? or I just missed something?

UPDATE: working code for main:

```
def connect_socket():
    socketIO = SocketIO('10.0.0.4',8080,Namespace)
    socketIO.wait()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyKeyboardListener() #keyboard listener, works fine
    socketThread = threading.Thread(target = connect_socket) #creat thread for socket
    socketThread.daemon = True #set daemon flag
    socketThread.start()
    SnakeApp().run
```

Comment: Have you tried running the SnakeApp() in the main thread, and SockedIO in a secondary thread (the reverse of the second not working example)? If it still doesn't work, try this: [link](https://kivy.org/docs/faq.html#fatal-python-error-pygame-parachute-segmentation-fault)

Comment: @jligeza thanks. well... It kind of works. But there is no way to exit the program. ctrl + c(or ctrl + z) makes the program freeze. I have to restart Pi then. If I take out the socketIO code then the program can exit with ctrl + c normally. This is weird, it must relate to the multithread thing

Comment: The easiest way to instantly kill the program on ctrl + c is to set the `daemon` flag for the secondary thread. Then, the secondary thread will be automatically killed once the primary thread is dead, finishing execution of the entire app.

Comment: @jligeza Thank you  so much! It works perfectly! You just saved my day(or night? lol)

Comment: Let me rewrite the answer to the answer panel, so other people with similar problem can find the solution more effectively. Then, please accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should run the kivy main loop in the primary thread, and the socket listing in a secondary thread (reverse of your second try that didn't work).

But it will leave your app hanging when you simply close it, because the secondary thread will keep it alive despite the primary thread being dead.

The easiest solution to this problem is to start the secondary thread with a `daemon = True` flag, so it will be killed as soon as the primary thread is dead.